# Writing data to an external topic with Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I would like to create a Kafka Streams application which is reading data from an internal Kafka topic and writing to an external one located on another cluster.

Is there any way to write to an external Kafka topic? How can I provide configurations via yaml file for such an application?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka Streams will only work with `to()` to the *same* cluster.

You can use alernative tools like MirrorMaker to send to a whole new cluster.

Otherwise, Flink/Spark can provide cross-cluster Kafka read/write actions.

> provide configurations via yaml file

*Kafka Streams* doesn't use YAML. Spring Boot, for example, does.